# What was the last of the Thinkpad X series with replaceable RAM?

Tags: ram, thinkpad

I know my x230 has replaceable RAM. I know the x395 lists its ram as being soldered. What is the last of the X series lineup with user-serviceable RAM?

Comment: Most thinkpads usually have one slot in additional to the soldered RAM. Lenovo needs a high RAM SKU most of the time, so the standard practice is to solder the RAM for the base model and use the slot for the high mem model. So check the services manual.

Comment: @user3528438 not any more, many of their current models only have soldered RAM and can’t be expanded after purchase.

Answer (score 2):

The last of the X2 range to have user-serviceable memory was the X270; the X280 has soldered memory only. The X390 and X395 only have soldered memory too (but they’re not part of the same range).

Comment: Although it would in theory be user replaceable for those with sufficient skill and equipment to desolder and replace it (surface mount soldering skills likely needed) it obviously does not count as "user replacement" . Suspect bios would allow different ram configs without too much complaint. Is a general trend towards not allowing user upgrades though generally i.e. Soldered in SSD's and in some cases portables that have regular removable memory but require substantial dismantling to get at it. I have a very old (dead) MSI netbook with this erm "feature"